# QML: Share list model between two gridview

Tags: qt, qml

I need to share a model list of items between two gridview because I need to move items between the two controls using drag and drop. The obvious solution is to use Package but in my case I have the problem the GridView show an empty space where an items should be also if the item is placed on the other view. A screen shot will crarify the problem. As you can see I add the block by disposing in the two view even and odd but this create the columns you can see. Someone know hwo to make the block to appear in the view in the "normal" order without the spaces?

[image]

Follow the example code:

```
GridView {
    id: grid1
    cellWidth: 80
    cellHeight: 80
    model: visualDelegateModel.parts.grid1
}

GridView {
    id: grid2
    cellWidth: 80
    cellHeight: 80
    model: visualDelegateModel.parts.grid2
}

ListModel {
    id: blocksListModel
    ListElement { color: "blue" }
    ListElement { color: "green" }
    ListElement { color: "red" }
    ListElement { color: "yellow" }
    ListElement { color: "orange" }
    ListElement { color: "purple" }
    ListElement { color: "cyan" }
    ListElement { color: "magenta" }
    ListElement { color: "chartreuse" }
    ListElement { color: "aquamarine" }
    ListElement { color: "indigo" }
    ListElement { color: "black" }
    ListElement { color: "lightsteelblue" }
    ListElement { color: "violet" }
    ListElement { color: "grey" }
    ListElement { color: "springgreen" }
    ListElement { color: "salmon" }
    ListElement { color: "blanchedalmond" }
    ListElement { color: "forestgreen" }
    ListElement { color: "pink" }
    ListElement { color: "navy" }
    ListElement { color: "goldenrod" }
    ListElement { color: "crimson" }
    ListElement { color: "teal" }
}

DelegateModel {
    id: visualDelegateModel
    delegate: Block {}
    model: blocksListModel
}
```

And this is the Block delegate:

```
Package {
    id: packageRoot

    Item { id: grid1Delegate; Package.name: "grid1"}
    Item { id: grid2Delegate; Package.name: "grid2" }

    Rectangle {
        id: block
        width: 72; height: 72
        anchors {
            horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter;
            verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
        color: model.color
        radius: 3

        state: (index % 2) ? "grid1" : "grid2"

        states: [
            State {
                name: "grid1"
                ParentChange { target: block; parent: grid1Delegate }
            },
            State {
                name: "grid2"
                ParentChange { target: block; parent: grid2Delegate }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to describe the issue. Some parts are missing around the GridViews to obtain the same renderer as you.

Comment: You could use two `QSortFilterProxyModel` to split the one root model in two models using some criteria to decide where to display it. To move it, you can then move the model entry to the right position in the root model and maybe set some role to change, in which model it will eventually be filtered.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion but Package is used just for have a single model anda allow an easy move of the item between views. Instead of split is possible to create two models for each view but in this case move item between views mean remove item from a model and attach to the other model that is not what I need...

Comment: As you can see, `Package` doesn't work - at least not as you are using it.

Comment: By changing the two Items contained in Block by `Text { id: grid1Delegate; width: 72; height: 72; text: 'Empty 1'; Package.name: 'grid1' } Text { id: grid2Delegate; width: 72; height: 72; text: 'Empty 2'; Package.name: 'grid2' }` you will see what is happening. Moreover, if you try to display `visualDelegateModel.parts.grid2.count`, you will obtain `24`. You don't really have submodels here.

Comment: At first thank you for the reply. What is happening is clear but I don't understan why is happening. What do you mean  with "You don't really have submodels here"?

Comment: `Package` just allows you to have different delegates for the same model. They also share a context, so they can reference each other. So what you do is, you create two `Item` and one `Rectangle` for each model entry. You reparent the `Rectangle` to one of those two Items. Then you show the first of the two Items in grid1 and the second in grid2. It is added and uses a cell, no matter the content.

Comment: You right, this is the exact situation. In the meanwhile I'm checking the way you suggested to use SortFilterProxyModel, hope to reach some result... ^_^